# Click event is working only in the circle centre

Tags: phaser-framework

When I use a circle, only its centre receives the event, if I click anywhere it doesn't work, only when I click in the circle centre.
How can I make the whole circle clickable?

```
const circle = this.add.circle(300, 300, 25, 0xff0000, 1);
circle.setInteractive();
circle.on('pointerdown', function() {
    console.log("click");
});
```

**Update**: Using phaser 3

Comment: Phaser 2 CE or Phaser 3 ?

Comment: Phaser 3 ......

Answer (score 1):

```js
var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    scene: {
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function create ()
{
    var graphics = this.add.graphics({ fillStyle: { color: 0xff0000 } });

    var circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(30, 30, 25);

    graphics.fillCircleShape(circle);

    this.input.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
      console.log("click")
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```