# interactive area is much smaller than the visible area of a filled circle

Tags: phaser-framework

I am adding some circles (filled with a color so I can see where they are). Each circle is setInteractive, listening for pointerdown.

**Problem**
I'd expect to be able to click anywhere within a circle and see the console.log output. In practise this only happens when I click quite a few pixels inside the circle, but not near the edges -  as if the interactive area is much smaller than the visible filled circle. I *think that the hit-area of my shape must be a rectangle, not a circle - but I can't work out how to make the hit-area the same as the rendered circle.*

```
var graphics = this.add.graphics({ fillStyle: { color: 0xff0000 } });
spotLayers.forEach(spotLayer => {
  spotLayer.spotMarkers.forEach(spotMarker => {

    var spotcircle = this.add.circle(spotMarker.x * (width / maxWidth), spotMarker.y * (height / maxHeight), 30 * (width / maxWidth));
    graphics.fillCircleShape(spotcircle);
    spotMarker.gameObject = spotcircle;

    spotMarker.gameObject.setInteractive();
    spotMarker.gameObject.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
      console.log('pointer x ' + pointer.x + ' pointer y ' + pointer.y);                        
    }, this);
  })
});
```

edit: just found this post, which implies my code is correct [Click event is working only in the circle centre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089416/click-event-is-working-only-in-the-circle-centre) - I still have the problem. What could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post from the phaser forum (thank you @samme) provided working code with a circular hit area (the default is rectangular)

```
spotLayers.forEach(spotLayer => {
  spotLayer.spotMarkers.forEach(spotMarker => {
    var spotcircle = this.add.circle(
      spotMarker.x * (width / maxWidth),
      spotMarker.y * (height / maxHeight),
      60 * (width / maxWidth),
      0xffff00, // fillColor
      0.5 // fillAlpha
    );

    spotcircle.setInteractive(
      new Phaser.Geom.Circle(
        0.5 * spotcircle.displayWidth, // center x
        0.5 * spotcircle.displayHeight, // center y
        spotcircle.radius // radius
      ),
      Phaser.Geom.Circle.Contains
    );

    console.log('hitArea', spotcircle.input.hitArea); // Geom.Circle

    // Makes a debug shape for the hit area (thin green stroke)
    // It should align with `spotcircle` texture (solid yellow)
    this.input.enableDebug(spotcircle);

    spotcircle.on(
      'pointerdown',
      function (pointer) {
        console.log('pointer x ' + pointer.x + ' pointer y ' + pointer.y);
      },
      this
    );

    spotMarker.gameObject = spotcircle;
  });
});
```